# How to send multiple pdfs in spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, pdf

I need to find out a way, how to efficiently do the following thing.

Someone will have a right to post `.pdf` documents and send it to all chosen users to read it and these users need to confirm that they are aware of that document. And I have `REST + JS client`

So basically I would have a database, where would be stored the path to file, who created that document etc...

But I need to show all documents to that user (so it might be like 10 documents to load for that user) so I would have to make like `10 endpoints` with given `.pdf` which is nonsense.

I need to make it somehow dynamically and also it must be really secure.

How can I do that any answer on it will be helpful?

Comment: That question is _very_ broad and thus I'd say out of scope for SO. Please read [ask] for some more info.

Comment: I'll still try to provide at least a little help: provide a single endpoint that accepts parameters like a user and document id and which sends back a single document. That way you can track which documents the user downloaded (you can't make sure they were actually read unless you test that by asking some questions ;) ). If a user is to be informed of a list of document he needs to be aware of then just send that list (the elements would contain a document id, a description etc.) and let the client application build a list of links to click using the one endpoint.

Comment: @Thomas thank you, that is exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @Thomas I am a little bit thinking about that... Lets say the url would be smthing like: localhost:8080/docs?doc_id=1 - then user might change id of that url and might possibly get access to document that he should not read for example... so I would need to create some longer special Ids which cannot be guessed... or different method... for example using jsons? would it be more secure?

Comment: `doc_id=1` should be ok - longer ids would be security by obscurity which isn't any security at all. Instead you would check whether the user is authorized to access that document and if not return 401 or whatever fits your needs.